# NSXMLParser didStartElement only with a certain attribute

Tags: ios, xml, sdk, nsxmlparser

Being said that I understand the basic parsing of XML files with NSXMLParser, I have the following situation, where I have several elements `<table_data>...</table_data>` which differ from each other for the value of a certain attribute, so, for example:

```
<table_data attr="one">...</table_data> 

<table_data attr="two">...</table_data>

<table_data attr="three">...</table_data>
```

While in didStartElement, I'd like that the parser takes into account the `<table_data>` element as the start element only if it has the `attr="one"`.

This would imply that in foundCharacters I could get only the content of children elements of `<table_data attr="one">` but not of `<table_data attr="two">`, `<table_data attr="three">`, etc.

By now, I try this:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString*)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary*)attributeDict {

    elementoCorrente = [elementName copy];

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"table_data"]) {

        if ([[attributeDict objectForKey:@"attr"] isEqualToString:@"one"]) {
            stringDesc = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        }

    }

}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {


    if ([elementoCorrente isEqualToString:@"field"]) {

        [stringDesc appendString:string];
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
    }


}
```

But what I get is the log of the content of the `<field>` element, child of all the `<table_data>`.
Is there a way to print only the content of the `<field>` element, if child of `<table_data attr="one">` ?
Thanks
Fabio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you do nothing to stop `foundCharacters` from appending data for the other occurrences of `table_data`. You could have your `didStartElement` save the `attributeDict[@"attr"]` value, too, and then `foundCharacters` could check both `elementoCorrente` as well as this new ivar in which you're holding the `attributeDict[@"attr"]` value. For example:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString*)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary*)attributeDict {

    elementoCorrente = nil;
    atributoCorrente = nil;

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"table_data"]) {

        if ([attributeDict[@"attr"] isEqualToString:@"one"]) {
            elementoCorrente = [elementName copy];
            atributoCorrente = [attributeDict[@"attr"] copy];
            stringDesc = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        }
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([elementoCorrente isEqualToString:@"table_data"] && [atributoCorrente isEqualToString:@"one"]) {

        [stringDesc appendString:string];
    }
}
```

Frankly, you probably want a `didEndElement` implementation, too, that saves `stringDesc` wherever you wanted to save it, and then sets `elementoCorrente` to `nil`.

Comment: This is, in my opinion, the right answer. And it is incredible how easy it was. Shame on me... Many thanks to Rob who took the time to provide me with working code too :) Also, the Helderdarocha's answer is a working and good one, thanks to both of you I can go on now!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the code fragment is missing something, but from what you are showing here, to print the content of all the `field` tags is the expected behavior, since the only test you make in the `parser:foundCharacters:` method is if the current element is `field`.

You could add a flag indicating that you are inside the `table_data` with `attr_one`. Something like:

```
if ([[attributeDict objectForKey:@"attr"] isEqualToString:@"one"]) {
    stringDesc = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    insideTableOne = YES;
}
```

And then, in the `parser:foundCharacters:` also test if `insideTableOne` is true before appending the string.

This test is also necessary so your program won't crash if it finds a `table_data` without the expected attribute. If that happens, `stringDesc` won't have been instantiated yet.